# How to dynamically create JPanel with given parameters?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have main `JFrame` in my project. And one main `JPanel` with `Y-AXIS BoxLayout` which is used to contain another panels in it. This is the way i use my `JFrame` to show this `JPanel` by default (I'm not quite convinced if this is the right way):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           mainPanel = new MainScreenPanel();
            MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
            mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
            mainFrame.invalidate();
            mainFrame.validate();
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Next I add two JPanels into `mainPanel` like this:

```
public class MainScreenPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public MainScreenPanel() {
        StatusPanel sPanel = new StatusPanel();
        LogPanel lPanel = new LogPanel();
        add(sPanel);
        add(lPanel);
    }

}
```

`lPanel` has different gui elements on it. One of them is a button which opens another panel (addConnectionPanel), and replaces `mainPanel` in the `jFrame` Here is the way i do it:

```
private void addCnctButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    topFrame.setContentPane(new AddConnectionPanel());
    topFrame.invalidate();
    topFrame.validate();
}
```

`AddConectionPanel` has some labels and input text boxes. It has two buttons `ok` and `cancel`. Here is the code of `cancel` button:

```
private void cancelCnctBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    topFrame.setContentPane(new MainScreenPanel());
    topFrame.invalidate();
    topFrame.validate();
}
```

`sPanel` is empty. It must be empty until input boxes on `AddConnectionPanel` are not filled and 'ok' button is not pressed. When these actions are performed, I want to dynamically create `JLabels` which take parameters from inputs on `sPanel`. Labels should be grouped, so when the actions performed second time new group must be created. Can some one give me advice on how to do this? And show me my mistakes? Keep in mind I'm using NetBeans.

Comment: Please adjust the indentation of the code snippets. Also, please post, what you have implemented in the AddConnectionPanel class so far.

Comment: @SME_Dev AddConnectionPanel class is standard JPanel, with TextLabels, TextInputs and two buttons. Has nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
public interface ConnectionPanelListener{
    void onOkButtonClicked(String... options);

    void onCancelButtonClicked();
}


public class AddConnectionPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ConnectionPanelListener listener;


    public AddConnectionPanel(){
        final Map<ConnectionOptions, JTextField> components = new HashMap<>(ConnectionOptions.values().length);

        for(ConnectionOptions option:ConnectionOptions.values()){
            this.add(new JLabel(option.labelCaption));

            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            //setup textField;
            this.add(textField);

            components.put(option, textField);
        }
        JButton button = new JButton("OK");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent pE) {
                super.mouseClicked(pE);
                //TODO validate TextFields

                Collection<String> inputs = new Stack<>();

                for(Entry<?,JTextField> e : components.entrySet()){
                    String text = e.getValue().getText();

                    if(text==null || text.trim().isEmpty()){
                        //TODO improve input validation
                        System.out.println("Input text is empty for: "+e.getKey());
                    } else {
                        inputs.add(e.getKey() + ": " + text);
                    }
                }
                listener.onOkButtonClicked(inputs.toArray(new String[inputs.size()]));
            }
        });
        this.add(button);
        button = new JButton("cancel");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent pE) {
                super.mouseClicked(pE);

                listener.onCancelButtonClicked();
            }
        });
        this.add(button);
    }

    public void setConnectionPanelListener(final ConnectionPanelListener l){
        listener = l;
    }

    private enum ConnectionOptions{
        IP_ADDRESS("IP-Address:"), PORT("Port:"), WHATEVER_ATTRIBUTE_YOU_NEED("Extras:"); 

        private String labelCaption;

        private ConnectionOptions(final String caption) {
            labelCaption = caption;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, AddConnectionPanel expects a Listener to register for the case, that "OK" or "CANCEL" are clicked. So your adjusted implementation could be like:

```
private void addCnctButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);

    AddConnectionPanel panel = new AddConnectionPanel();
    panel.setConnectionPanelListener(new ConnectionPanelListener(){

        @Override
        void onOkButtonClicked(String... options){ TODO: fill sPanel using the given Strings }

        @Override
        void onCancelButtonClicked(){ TODO }
    });

    topFrame.setContentPane(panel);
    topFrame.invalidate();
    topFrame.validate();
}
```

Comment: Thx, helped me to understand concept